# How to use an extensibility dll for designer support

Tags: .net, design-time

I've written a UITypeEditor and it works when the editor lives in the same assembly (or one of the referenced assemblies) as the types using it. Then I can use something like:

```
[Editor(typeof(MyUIEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
```

However, I'd like to move this to a separate assembly, one that is not referenced by the assemblies with types that use it, because I don't want to have to distribute the code that is solely to for the VS designer. I know this can be done, but can't figure out how to setup the editor/where to put the extensibility assembly to get it to work. I've tried this:

```
[Editor("MyProject.Extensibility.MyUIEditor, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e54367fa007b34d2", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
```

And copied the extensibility assembly into the bin\debug folder with the main project.  No joy.

How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a different question that was a bit more focused and got the answer. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628264/how-is-an-assembly-resolved-at-design-time) related to referencing a UITypeEditor in another assembly.  The trick is to set a registry key (or put in GAC).